# Find the namespaces from xml with python ElementTree with redeclared namespaces

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

How do you acquire proper namespace if a namespace definition is re-declared? To elaborate: the prefix is the same but the attribute value is different, thus redeclared.

i.e `<site:Stack xmlns:site='http://stackoverflow.com'>` 
to
 `<site:Stack xmlns:site='https://math.stackexchange.com/'>`

From what I read in XML docs from Microsoft, this is accepted and it's merely *re-declaring the namespace*. **Unless** this is unaccepted form, then I can just close this question.

It's a problem because it messes up most dictionary approaches to acquire namespace, but it also messes up the `ElementTree.register_namespace(prefix, uri)` method from the Standard library.
Register_namespace is quite important as it is used to resolve namespace tags as ET parsing gives out tags in clark notation, for example the Header Element, as 
`<{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}:Header/>`
Using register_namespace resolves the above back to `<SOAP-ENV:Header/>`.
This causes serious issues for me as I am de-serializing XML into a custom class object, and then re-serializing (after some processing/edits) to a well-formed XML file.

i.e. from Oracle's XML examples. 
Note how Orders changes to Confirm, but same prefix.

`<PO:order xmlns:PO="http://gizmos.com/orders/">` changes to 
`<PO:confirmation xmlns:PO="http://gizmos.com/confirm">`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
        <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Message does not have necessary info</faultstring>
        <faultactor>http://gizmos.com/order</faultactor>
            <detail>
                <PO:order xmlns:PO="http://gizmos.com/orders/">
                Quantity element does not have a value
                </PO:order>
                <PO:confirmation xmlns:PO="http://gizmos.com/confirm">
                Incomplete address: no zip code
                </PO:confirmation>
            </detail>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

As a note: I am aware you can acquire a dictionary with the namespaces using the following. But this will use the most recent declaration of any namespace. Likewise ET.register_namespace will do the same, which is most recent declaration is used.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
my_namespaces = dict([
    node for (_, node) in ET.iterparse('file.xml', events=['start-ns'])
])
```

Comment: As far as I know, it is legal to use the same prefix for two different namespace URIs. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/41774652/407651.

Comment: From that answer, it would appear the XML above given by Oracle is actually invalid. The answer you linked states that NameSpace is allowed to be the same, but ultimately the Xpath Mapping must be unique. So in my example, PO cannot map to both Order and Confirmation.

Comment: I don't think your XML example is "invalid". I have parsed it using Python's ElementTree module as well as xmllint and there were no errors.

Comment: I am aware its "valid" but well formed is another question which I am not sure. Like I mentioned in my original post, register_namespace does not work.

I have read it in as an ET, broken it down, and reserialized it back into an ET. However like I said before, standard library function calls do not work with it because there are two duplicate prefixes PO.

Even in the answer you linked to me, the answer explicitly mentions that every mapping must be unique.

Comment: The document is well-formed. If it wasn't, the parsers would have thrown errors. I'd say that it is unusual (and confusing) to have the same prefix for two different namespaces, but it does not break any rules for XML documents.

Comment: I see. Well, even if it is well formed and etc, the issue is that it does not work well with et.register_namespace. Inherently, you must feed in a dictionary to resolve namespaces, and of course you cannot have a duplicate mapping in a dictionary. So unfortunately it seems my solution is to not use the ET.register_namespace method and manually address duplicate prefixes in my custom deserializer/serializer logic I've built up. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XML is well formed and works. In a scenario where you are only using ElementTree from the standard lib, ElementTree.register_namespace(prefix, uri) cannot be used to resolve namespaces as the dictionary you feed in as arguments will not work as you will have duplicate prefixes with different URI's, which is also invalid for a python dictionary.

There is a solution if xpath is used, which uses unique mapping to the prefixes. So using the oracle xml as an example. `P1 maps to PO to http://gizmos.com/orders/`, and `P2 maps to PO to http://gizmos.com/confirm/`

Without editing the original XML and using only ElementTree, one will have to manually address this.